# Remove favorites from sidebar

Tags: nautilus

I followed the [tutorial lifehacker gave](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony) about dual-booting win 7 and ubuntu but when I come to ubuntu I can't remove my inner documents and music libraries in favour of my common libraries store in another partition. How can I remove them from sidebar? should I ask for extra permissions or type my password anywhere? thanks

**edit**:  I have no problem accessing the storage or accessing my files. The thing i want is to remove the default libraries from the sidebar I see then I open any folder and to add instead of them my folders (located on storage partition)

Comment: Please make your question clearer - do you have problems accessing a Storage partition or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

To find it, open your Home folder, press `Ctrl+H` in order to see hidden files, navigate to `.config` and open the `user-dirs.dirs` file.

You'll see something like

```
    XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
    XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
    XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
    XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
    XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
    XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
    XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
    XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Just replace `$HOME/yyy` with `\path\to\the\folder\you\want`

Note that:

1. in order for the changes to take effect, you have to log out and log back in.
2. I wasn't able to add or remove entries, just change them.